# Axios not working in AWS Lambda with Google Servers

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, axios

I am currently experiencing a weird issue.

I use axios in my **NodeJS Lambda (AWS)** to verify a Google Recaptcha Token.
However, this request to Google via `axios.post()` takes forever and therefore the Lambda function gets a timeout. (10s)

At first I thought it might be the VPC or the Security Group but no, I commented out the request and sent **another request via axios which works**.
Only the one via Google does not work. (On my local machine it works of course).

The code I use for posting to Google:

```
const response = await axios.post(
      `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${recaptchaSecret}&response=${event.token}`
    );
```

I have already put a try / catch block around it and no errors are printed / catched.

Looking forward to your suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: Is your lambda running inside a VPC?

Comment: Yes, and the security group has access to all outgoing IPs. As mentioned above when I send another post() request (e.g. to slack) it works perfectly fine just the google request ist not working on Lambda.

Comment: You say this works from your local machine. What local environment does it work in? Node.js or browser?

Comment: NodeJs Environment.